# Infobip with aws to send files by whatsapp

Tags: node.js, amazon-s3, infobip-api

I am trying to integrate infobip to my project but there is an error saying: Error al cargar o enviar el archivo: TypeError: infobip.InfobipClient is not a constructor. I have checked my credentials and it looks ok, but the error is still there. The url is being created correctly from aws.

I tried to change my credentials with my password and also with the api key created at infobip. I uninstalled and install infobip too.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.